# Google Crawl Error on "search_rss" URLs in Plone

Tags: plone, google-search-console

I'm running a site using Plone 4.2.1. The site has been being indexed by Google for a couple of years now (using Plone sitemap addon).

Since 2 months ago, suddenly Crawl Errors section in Google Webmaster is getting filled up with hundreds of errors. All of these errors are of the form `SOME_VALID_URL/search_rss...`.

Now the questions is what has caused Google to start indexing these non-existing URLs? Is there a way to fix this?

TIA,

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to Plone 4.3.2.

This is the Fix: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/commit/bce722877ebedc92c7b1dfc6c09a28bc3bc2748e

I don't know which version introduce this bug. 
I my case it was a upgrade from `Plone 3.3.5` to `4.3.1`.
`Plone 3.3.5` worked fine. `Plone 4.3.1` didn't.

The fix raises NotFound, so google will no longer index the particular url.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias. If that is the only solution, well, I will do it. Do you have any idea why all of sudden Google started to index those `search_rss` URLs?

Comment: @BahmanM. I guess google indexed those urls before, and they were kind of valid ;-) btw. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I will do the upgrade (eew!) and mark your answer as the correct one if it fixes the error :-)